# Android OAuth Implementation using WebView

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implment the `OAuth` flow for live connect through an android app. For the authentication and consent part, I am using `WebView` to redirect the user to the corresponding pages. The flow that I am trying to implement is -

1. Launch `MyActivity`.
2. In `onCreate()`, launch `auth url` and wait.
3. User logs in using an account and is redirected to consent page.
4. User agrees to access permissions.
5. Parse auth code.
6. Return to `MyActivity` and perform actions using `auth` code.

Below is the code snippet :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
          AuthFlowWebView authView = new AuthFlowWebView(); //AuthFlowWebView extends WebViewClient
          myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          myWebView.setWebViewClient(authView);
          myWebView.loadUrl("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=wl.signin%20wl.offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf&display=touch");
          Log.i("", "Here already before the auth process is complete");
          }
    }

//Here is the Overriden onPageFinished method used to parse the auth code in AuthFlowWebView class:
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Thread.dumpStack();
            if (url.contains("oauth20_desktop.srf?code=")) {
                authSuccess = true;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                authCode = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
                Log.i("", "CODE : " + authCode);
                authProcessComplete = true;
            }
```

I am stuck with making `MyActivity` wait until steps 3-5 are complete. Please suggest alternatives to implement such a flow.

Answer (score 2):

Updated my WebViewClient implementation as given below, that fixed the problem. Hope someone finds this useful.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        boolean authComplete = false;
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

        @Override public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
         pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(), "",
                    "Connecting to " + provider + " server", false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                pDialog.dismiss();

            if (url.contains("?code=") && authComplete != true) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                authCode = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
                Log.i("", "CODE : " + authCode);
                authComplete = true;
                resultIntent.putExtra("code", authCode);
                WebActivity.this
                        .setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                resultIntent.putExtra("status", WebActivity.Status.SUCCESS.toString());
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }else if(url.contains("error=access_denied")){
                Log.i("", "ACCESS_DENIED_HERE");
                resultIntent.putExtra("code", authCode);
                resultIntent.putExtra("status", WebActivity.Status.ACCESS_DENIED.toString());
                authComplete = true;
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```